# JPA Null parent foreign key in child entity

Tags: java, mysql, entity-framework, hibernate, jpa

I can't associate set the child foreign key to the parent in a OneToMany bidirectional relationship. I have a parent class Union defined this way:

```
@Entity
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(referencedColumnName="id")
@Table(name="union_tb")
@Inheritance( strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED )     
public class Union extends User{

@Column(unique=true)
String Name;
float uniondue = 0;


@OneToMany(targetEntity=ServiceCharge.class,cascade=CascadeType.REMOVE, orphanRemoval=true,fetch = FetchType.EAGER,mappedBy="union")
List<ServiceCharge> ServiceCharges;
@OneToMany(targetEntity=Employee.class,cascade=CascadeType.REMOVE, orphanRemoval=true,fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
List<Employee> Employee;

public void PostServiceCharge(ServiceCharge charge) {
    ServiceCharges.add(charge);

}
```

And a child class ServiceCharge defined this way:

```
@Entity
@Table
 public class ServiceCharge implements Serializable{


@Id @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.AUTO)
int ChargeID;
String Service;
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
Calendar  TimeStamp;
float ChargeAmount;
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="union_id")
Union union;

public ServiceCharge(){super();}




public ServiceCharge(float chargeAmount, String service, String timestamp/*, Union union*/) throws ParseException {
    super();
    ChargeAmount = chargeAmount;
    Service = service;
    TimeStamp = TimeManagUtil.getGCobjectfromString(timestamp);
    //this.Union = union;
}

// getters and setters
}
```

Then i run the test code:

```
    @Test
public void Test() throws Exception {
    ServiceCharge charge1 = new ServiceCharge(60,"service for employee","27/11/2016 20:35:00");
    Union u = new Union("Sindacate", 80);
    UnionController.add(u);
    ServiceController.add(charge1, u);
}
```

As you can see, i'm associating with a controller the two entities after persisting Union u into the database, ServiceController.add just adds the entity charge1 to the list of servicecharges by using a Union setter and then persist the entity into the database.

However, the test goes correctly, but i can only see this:

```
 | ChargeID | ChargeAmount | Service              | TimeStamp           | union_id |
 +----------+--------------+----------------------+---------------------+----------+
 |        6 |           60 | service for employee | 2016-11-27 20:35:00 |     NULL |
 |        7 |           10 | service for employee | 2016-11-27 20:45:00 |     NULL


 | Name      | uniondue | id |
 +-----------+----------+----+
 | Sindacate |       80 |  5 |
 +-----------+----------+----+
```

As you can see, union_id is set to null. What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try to Instantiate First the `Union` Class, and Initialize it in the Constructor of ServiceCharge.

```
@Test
public void Test() throws Exception {
    Union u = new Union("Sindacate", 80);
    UnionController.add(u);
    ServiceCharge charge1 = 
              new ServiceCharge(60,"service for employee","27/11/2016 20:35:00", u); // uncomment your parameter here that accepts Union class type.
    ServiceController.add(charge1, u);
}
```

Comment: You saved me. In fact, it is even right conceptually, since a Service Chargé cannot exist without a Union associated with it. But now, I have the identical same problem with the Employee relationship, but now i should not call Union into the constructor since now it can be even null and i don't like the idea of passing null as a parameter everytime.

Comment: so what is the output so far? I think you can Overload your Contructor so you can select what constructor you should use. So you can have options. A Constructor that has union parameter and a Constructor that has not a union parameter.

Comment: I can't go that way, since an Employee can decide later after being instantiated to be associated with a union. Null values are allowed.

Comment: So change your unionid in ServiceCharge not to null values. put this annotation in your Union. `@Column(nullable = false)`

Comment: And what's the point if the problem is between Union and Employee?  Maybe i could try merging the Employee after applying the relationship.